# NCover with a C++/CLI assembly

Tags: c++-cli, ncover

Does anybody know how to do coverage of an C++/CLI class using NCover?

NCover only measures coverage of an assembly if it finds a matching .pdb file.

However, my C++/CLI project does not output a .pdb file.

If I go to "Visual Studio -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Output Files -> Program Database File Name" and set it to "MyDll.pdb" it actually outputs a file called "MyDLL.idb"!?

Comment: The PDB files contain the line # to IL mappings - I always produce them and I have never known them to have any noticeable impact on running code (until exceptions start happening and then they are used to give comprehensive stack traces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, confuzzling setting.  It is actually a linker setting: Linker, Debugging, Generate Program Database File.  Make sense if you think about it, only after linking are all object files combined and can debug info be created.

Not sure why you'd have to jump through this hoop, the default settings in the Debug configuration ensure that a .pdb file is created.  Ought to be good enough for NCover, I'd imagine.

Comment: Thank you, this helped. I had to turn on debug info in c++ and in linker settings. Then the pdb-File was created and NCover reported coverage correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you compiling a Release build, or Debug build? As Hans mentioned, the default settings for Debug will generate a .pdb that NCover can use.

Comment: Right, that was the problem. We do not do a debug build, since its a long running algorithm, which takes for ever in debug mode.